# Arduino port stuck on full power

Tags: java, serial-port, arduino

I am working on a system that rings a bell when someone decides to ring it or it is timed. This also includes emergency bells, such as when there is an earthquake threat or an armed intruder. On the armed intruder bell it rings for .5 seconds (500ms) and then waits 1.5s (1500ms) and repeats. However, on the fourth cycle the bell gets stuck on and will stay on until I turn the arduino off. I have tried many ways of trying to fix it but it will not work. I will post my code below and could someone have a look and see what is wrong with it?

Thank you!

Java for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    out.write("500".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        out.flush();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Arduino Code:

```
int Relay = 13;
//The pin that the relay is attached to
//int time;
//Creates temp variable

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(Relay, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    while(true) {
        //Check if data has been sent from the computer:
        if (Serial.available()) {
              int time;
          //Assign serial value to temp
          time = Serial.parseInt();
          //Output value to relay

              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
          delay(time);
          digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting a small delay into the if-loop, after checking and before reading from the Serial (just a few ms. Maybe put your 1000ms delay at the beginning). As the data arrive serialized, and you check with a high frequency, it might be, that the program starts reading out data before everything is received.

I don't know how exactly Serial.parseInt() works, but maybe try:

```
out.write("500\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

in your Java-loop